# how to add another byte array into onpreviewframe's byte array in surfaceview in android

Tags: android, camera, arrays, surfaceview

Actually i need to do simple task
add logo into video created by surface View

First i did that convert logo image to byte array and successfully able to do so
in next phase need to add logo byte array to OnPreviewFrame method's parameter Byte[] xxx

how can i add these two byte array

is there any way for video recording using surface view with my static application logo on corner of video.

following my code:

```
@Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

            if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
                if (nextFrametime == -1) {
                    nextFrametime = startTime;
                }
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextFrametime) {
                    videoTimestamp = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

                    // Put the camera preview frame right into the yuvIplimage
                    // object

                    yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);
                    try {

                        // Get the correct time
                        recorder.setTimestamp(videoTimestamp);

                        // Record the image into FFmpegFrameRecorder
                        recorder.record(yuvIplimage);

                        recordError = false;

                    } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                        recordError = true;
                        nextFrametime = -1;
                        frameCount = 0;
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    nextFrametime = startTime
                            + (long) ((1000.0 / 15) * (++frameCount));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is no such thing like "video recording using surface view", there is however "video preview using surface view"

Comment: thanks for guide but @pskink i am currently not making video using onpreviewframe but passing byteArray to  wowza server for streaming. so can we modify byte array?for that can you guide ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add an overlay on top of the preview frames, kind of a watermark for the video you produce. You will get best results if you handle this with *[ffmpeg on native level](http://www.idude.net/index.php/how-to-watermark-a-video-using-ffmpeg/)*, but for JavaCV, see the *[tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/OpenCV2_Cookbook_Examples_Chapter_2#Example%3a_Blending_of_Images)*.

Comment: thanks Alex , Exactly like water mark image on corner of video but can  you please suggest me how can i use in my case? because i am developing for android and coding must be from java side and another requirement is how apply this effect to byte array of camera object in onpreviewFrame?

Comment: If the number of effected pixels is small, you can do this in Java inside `onPreviewFrame()`. Also, the answer depends on the merge formulae (how you handle transparency, etc). But [the example I linked to](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/OpenCV2_Cookbook_Examples_Chapter_2#Example%3a_Blending_of_Images) shows how you can do this generally, using JavaCV (you are using it in your project, aren't you)? Another note is that this watermark will not appear in the preview SurfaceView.